# Black plastic balls on reservoir to reduce evaporation - why black?

Tags: thermodynamics

The story is [here](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/california-drought-thousands-black-plastic-balls-released-into-reservoir-stop-water-shortages-1515378)

It states:

> The balls sit on top of the water and block the sunlight from hitting
> it, helping to reduce water evaporation as well as natural
> contamination and certain chemical reactions that could cause algae
> blooms in the reservoirs.

My question is that if they are to prevent evaporation why are they black? They will heat up far more than (say) white ones.

Comment: The main reason of the balls is to prevent photoinduced chemical reactions of chlorine and bromine (casuing carcinogenic chemicals), the reduced evaporation is only a side bonus (relatively small to the total water consumption). I assume they made the balls black to absorp as much light as possible to prevent these reactions to happen.

Answer (score 2):

White plastic balls scatter rather than absorb light. Scattered light has a certain probability of transmission (ping pong balls are translucent, for example). This means that UV light, in particular, has a certain probability of being transmitted into the liquid below - where it will continue to stimulate the algae growth that they are trying to stop.

Reflective balls would be even better - send the solar radiation straight back whence it came - but I imagine those are more expensive to manufacture.

Black balls will have the disadvantage of absorbing a lot of solar heat - I worry that the reservoir will get substantially hotter (a good fraction of sunlight reflects off the water but most of it will be absorbed by the balls). Combined with reduced evaporation, the water will become much warmer. I hope somebody did the calculation...